# Augmented Reality in Android studio

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality

I have just started developing an android application based on augmented reality. Its main concept is to identify an object (here laptop) and place an image on top of it.

I would like to know an easy solution or method to solve and the way to detect the laptop sufrace. and also which SDK can be used.

I've had some sites referred to me, such as:

- https://www.raywenderlich.com/158580/augmented-reality-android-googles-face-api
- https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore

Comment: StackOverflow is not the right place to ask for recommendations on SDKs or other resources as those lead to opinionated answers.
You are better off with a forum here. Your question is appreciated but this is simply the wrong place to ask for what you need.

Comment: First result when searching "Augmented reality Android studio" [was this](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/quickstart)

Comment: I have already gone through it, but the sample app which was provided was crashing.

Comment: You don't see many AR apps that reliably identify objects and place images on top of them; that's because there is (at this date) no *easy solution or method to solve* this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Vuforia's object recognition feature https://library.vuforia.com/content/vuforia-library/en/articles/Training/Object-Recognition.html to perform this specific task . 
I have tested it out and works pretty well . There are a few other sdk that offer this feature like EASY AR , but all these comes at a price. You can test it out using a developer license key for free though.

Let me know how development goes on android studio(On Unity its really easy).
Cheers.

Kewal

Answer (score 0):

You can try ARCore SDK with sceneform in Android Studio. Also Vuforia SDK available to do the same.
If you are looking a solution in Unity 3D, then also you can try this too plugins.

https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/downloads

https://developer.vuforia.com/